# didn't return an HttpResponse

Tags: django

Good morning, when I try to send the form, I get the error, and when I send it, it generates that my view does not return any httpresponse object.

this is the view

```
class ProductView(View):
    template_name = 'products/product.html'
    model = Product
    form_class = ProductForm

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.filter(state=True)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = {}
        context['product'] = self.get_queryset()
        context['list_product'] = self.form_class
        return context

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, self.template_name, self.get_context_data())

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        list_product = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if list_product.is_valid():
            list_product.save()
            return redirect('products:product')
```

and this is the form

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name_product = forms.CharField(
        max_length=25,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'id': 'name_product',
            }
        )
    )

    def clean_name_product(self):
        name_product = self.cleaned_data.get('name_product')
        if Product.objects.filter(name_product=name_product).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('El nombre del producto ya existe')
        return name_product

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = (
            'name_product', 'description', 'price', 'category', 'state', 'image'
        )
        labels = {
            'name_product': 'Nombre del Producto',
            'description': 'Descripcion',
            'price': 'Precio',
            'category': 'Categoria',
            'state': 'Estado',
            'image': 'Imagen del Producto',
        }
        widgets = {
            'name_product': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control',
                    'id': 'name_product',
                }
            ),
            'description': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control',
                    'id': 'description',
                }
            ),
            'price': forms.NumberInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control',
                    'id': 'price',
                }
            ),
            'category': forms.SelectMultiple(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'custom-select',
                    'id': 'category',
                }
            ),
            'state': forms.CheckboxInput(),
        }
```

when I give send it generates the error.The view products.views.ProductView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

At the beginning I thought that the error is due to the error lifting in the form, change the code without the validation and it generates the same error

Comment: If the `form` is not valid, you do not return anything in the `post` method.

Comment: but if the form validates well

Comment: well since you do not render the errors, you do not know if it is a valid form, and it does not render the form with errors :)

Comment: I already checked the code and you are right it does not pass the validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case the `form.is_valid()` fails, you do not return anything in the `post` method, hence the error. That being said, this is basically just a [**`CreateView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView), so it might be better to use that to reduce the amount of "boilerplate" code:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView

class ProductView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'products/product.html'
    model = Product
    form_class = ProductForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update(
            product=Product.objects.filter(state=True),
            list_product=context['form']
        )
        return context
```

Comment: Thank you very much it was very helpful, I have been looking for the error for 2 hours, and thanks for the advice that I had not taken it into account.